# Resizing JTable that's in a JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jtable, jpanel

Here's my code my `JTabel` that's in a `JPanel`, I'm currently running into a problem with the resizing. It just occupies the WEST of the GUI, and I'm trying to make it occupy the bottom left corner without going all the way up. Here is my code:

```
public void table(JFrame f) 
{

  String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name"};

  Object[][] players = {
                    {"John", "Doe"},
                    {"Steve", "White"}
  };

  JTable table = new JTable(players, columnNames);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

  table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 

  JPanel container = new JPanel();
  container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,300)); //This seems very wrong
  container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  container.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  container.add(table, BorderLayout.WEST);

  f.add(container);

  f.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line of the code

```
  container.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

You say that, BorderLayout.PAGE_START. Instead of the PAGE_START, you should define it to the place, where you want to put your component with the help of the picture below.

[image]

For more information, you can read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)